# BASH:- Parse string into separate command line arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I have the following bash code and want to convert the string into command line arguments to pass to a different program.

So I have GETVARS and want to split and do something like

./somecommand $GETVARS[0] $GETVARS[1]

and so on

GETVARS will be any random length of elements.

```
  GETVARS = ""
        for id in {100..500..10}
            do
                for letter in A B C D E F
                do
                    GETVARS=$GETVARS"\":${id}:${letter}\" "
                done
        done
  //GETVARS = "":100:A" "100:B" "100:C"" .. and so on
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with

```
getvars="" # no spaces around commas, use smaller case variable names
```

and from the requirement, you're clearly looking for a simple array like

```
getvars=() # or do declare -a getvars
```

I'm not clear about the requirement, but below is what I guess you should do

```
for id in {100..500..10}
  do
for letter in A B C D E F
  do
    getvars+=( \":${id}:${letter}\" ) # adding elements to array
 done
done
#and later do the following
./somecommand "${getvars[@]}" # Each element will be separated to a word
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I needed